# Unity Animation Rigging Local and World Position Problem

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, animation, constraints, inverse-kinematics

I have a problem with changing TwoBone IK target positions.
If i move a parent of the constraint targets while previewing as an animation, the moving will work.
[image: I didn't see the problem until i run a game]
During runtime manually moving targets is the only working way. If i move a parent, there won't be any changes in object's mesh.
[image: And then i reached a problem]

So my main question:
How could i make a target's world position response of an TwoBone IK Constraint?

My guesses ended with the fact that mesh responds only on the local position... But then, why at the start it counts world position of a targets?

Comment: Could you try to move the parent transform in the lateupdate function at runtime to see if it works ?

Comment: @ÇağatayIŞIK, thank you for answer. As you can see [HERE](https://www.veed.io/view/23404bd0-efa7-4e59-b113-0d169627c69c?panel=share) i made a rotation in LateUpdate() function, but it doesn't work. Only if i move a targets itself or by animating these targets. But what if i want to give a weapon to my character? I can change the targets for Constraints, but if i rotate a weapon, it doesn't affects to the character's hands.
Thanks for the answer again.